# Apply bolding to portion of NSAttributedString, while preserving font sizes and faces

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsattributedstring

I'm working on a rich text editor for iOS, using a `UITextView` along with an `NSAttributedString`. It'll function similarly to traditional ones (i.e. selecting a region, clicking a button, and it applies that effect to that region, while preserving any other attributes on the text.

Unfortunately with `NSAttributedString`, not all of them can be adjusted independently. Several of them (at least bold, font face, and font size) all require passing a `UIFont`, which'll set all of those attributes for the region (even if you only wanted to set one). Seeing as a single region might include several faces and sizes, this'll result in the naive approach breaking a lot of existing formatting.

Is there any recommended means to accomplish this? I'm thinking my only option will be to iterate through the attributes for the region I want to apply it to, group it into chunks that have the same other font attributes, and then apply it to each chunk individually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the right idea and the algorithm is already provided for you by `enumerateAttribute:inRange:options:usingBlock:`. To use this to process font runs:

```
[myAttributedString enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                               inRange:selectedRange
                               options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
                            usingBlock:addBoldBlock
]
```

where *addBoldBlock* takes the current font (supplied as first argument to the block), adds bold, and applies it to the current chunk (supplied as second argument to the block).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my DTRichTextEditor:

```
- (void)toggleBoldInRange:(NSRange)range
{
    // first character determines current boldness
    NSDictionary *currentAttributes = [self typingAttributesForRange:range];

    if (!currentAttributes)
    {
        return;
    }

    [self beginEditing];

    CTFontRef currentFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)[currentAttributes objectForKey:(id)kCTFontAttributeName];
    DTCoreTextFontDescriptor *typingFontDescriptor = [DTCoreTextFontDescriptor fontDescriptorForCTFont:currentFont];

    // need to replace name with family
    CFStringRef family = CTFontCopyFamilyName(currentFont);
    typingFontDescriptor.fontFamily = (__bridge NSString *)family;
    CFRelease(family);

    typingFontDescriptor.fontName = nil;

    NSRange attrRange;
    NSUInteger index=range.location;

    while (index < NSMaxRange(range)) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *attrs = [[self attributesAtIndex:index effectiveRange:&attrRange] mutableCopy];
        CTFontRef currentFont = (__bridge CTFontRef)[attrs objectForKey:(id)kCTFontAttributeName];

        if (currentFont)
        {
            DTCoreTextFontDescriptor *desc = [DTCoreTextFontDescriptor fontDescriptorForCTFont:currentFont];

            // need to replace name with family
            CFStringRef family = CTFontCopyFamilyName(currentFont);
            desc.fontFamily = (__bridge NSString *)family;
            CFRelease(family);

            desc.fontName = nil;

            desc.boldTrait = !typingFontDescriptor.boldTrait;
            CTFontRef newFont = [desc newMatchingFont];
            [attrs setObject:(__bridge id)newFont forKey:(id)kCTFontAttributeName];
            CFRelease(newFont);

            if (attrRange.location < range.location)
            {
                attrRange.length -= (range.location - attrRange.location);
                attrRange.location = range.location;
            }

            if (NSMaxRange(attrRange)>NSMaxRange(range))
            {
                attrRange.length = NSMaxRange(range) - attrRange.location;
            }

            [self setAttributes:attrs range:attrRange];
        }

        index += attrRange.length;
    }

    [self endEditing];
}
```

This uses DTCoreTextFontDescriptor from the open source DTCoreText project.

PS: You'd have to adjust it for use with UIFont accordingly.