# How to apply bold and italics to an NSMutableAttributedString range?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I've been trying to apply combinations of NSFontAttributes to NSMutableAttributedString's lately and I simply can't find a thorough explanation on how to do it without removing other attributes.

I've searched a bunch, and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023027/how-to-apply-both-bold-and-italic-font-to-an-nsattributedstring) pertaining to how to do it with HTML, and then this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294179/select-bold-and-italicized-text-from-textfield) about how to *find* where text has been bolded or italicized, but nothing on how to actually do it.

Currently, I try to format stings as follows:

**Italics:** 
`[mutableAttributedString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:[fontAttributes valueForKey:CXItalicsFontAttributeName] range:r];`

**Bold:** `[mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[fontAttributes valueForKey:CXBoldFontAttributeName] range:r];`

Where the constants `CXItalicsFontAttributeName` and `CXBoldAttributeName` extract the following two values from a dictionary respectfully:

```
UIFont *italicsFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-BookOblique" size:14.0f];
UIFont *boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Heavy" size:14.0f];
```

I know this mustn't be the right way to go about formatting, as the NSAttributedString [standard attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/standardAttributes.html) don't include a ItalicsFontAttribute or BoldFontAttribute, but I can't find the properly way to do this. Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're applying each (bold or italic) trait individually, you need to make sure that bold and italic ranges don't overlap or one trait will overwrite the other.

The only way to apply both bold *and* italic traits to a range is to use a font which is both bold and italic, and apply the both traits at once.

```
let str = "Normal Bold Italics BoldItalics"

let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 14.0)!
let italicsFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-BookOblique", size: 14.0)!
let boldFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 14.0)!
let boldItalicsFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir-HeavyOblique", size: 14.0)!

let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : font])
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: boldFont, range: NSMakeRange(7, 4))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: italicsFont, range: NSMakeRange(12, 7))
attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: boldItalicsFont, range: NSMakeRange(20, 11))
```

[image]

Comment: This method seems impractical. It means that I will need to create as many combinations as possible to try and account for all cases. I was hoping to avoid it.

Comment: @Owatch Here's [a question that asks about enumerating](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14161254/4151918).  You'll still need to construct the fonts on the fly.  There's no way around that.

Comment: I had selected your answer as the solution earlier as I couldn't find any alternatives, but have since found something a bit more suited to what I was looking for, so I removed the checkmark. I apologize for being inconsistent.

Comment: My original question was written knowing that a BoldItalicsFont did exist. However, I misunderstood that these things could not be 'layered' so to speak, and that they were entirely individual fonts of their own I would have to apply. I can see that it was unclear though, so I guess if you think your answer is best suited to the question as it stands, I can select it again.

Comment: It's all good!  Unfortunately, there's just no way to apply traits independent of the font, since those traits are specific to each font.

Answer (score 41):

In Swift and using an extension:

```
extension UIFont {

    func withTraits(_ traits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont {

        // create a new font descriptor with the given traits
        guard let fd = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(traits) else {
            // the given traits couldn't be applied, return self
            return self
        }
            
        // return a new font with the created font descriptor
        return UIFont(descriptor: fd, size: pointSize)
    }

    func italics() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(.traitItalic)
    }

    func bold() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits(.traitBold)
    }

    func boldItalics() -> UIFont {
        return withTraits([ .traitBold, .traitItalic ])
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 30) {
    let s = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font.italic() ])
    let t = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: [ NSFontAttributeName: font.boldItalic()) ])
}
```

Comment: Great answer, @nyg

Answer (score 8):

The best solution to my problem so far has been to make use of the `UIFontDescriptor` class to provide me with the necessary `UIFont` for each case I encounter.

For instance, as I want to use `Avenir-Book` as my primary font with size `14`, I can create a `UIFontDescriptor` as follows:

`UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:@"Avenir-Book" size:14.0f];`

Next, if I wish to obtain the Italicized, Bolded, or combination of both, I have simple to do as follows:

```
NSString *normalFont = [[fontDescriptor fontAttributes]valueForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
NSString *italicsFont = [[[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic]fontAttributes]valueForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
NSString *boldFont = [[[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold]fontAttributes]valueForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
NSString *boldAndItalicsFont = [[[fontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitBold | UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic]fontAttributes]valueForKey:UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute];
```

And this indeed produces the required fonts when printed:

```
NSLog(@"Normal Font: %@ Size: %@\n",normalFont,[[fontDescriptor fontAttributes]valueForKey:UIFontDescriptorSizeAttribute]);
NSLog(@"Italics Font: %@\n",italicsFont);
NSLog(@"Bold Font: %@\n",boldFont);
NSLog(@"Bold and Italics Font: %@\n",boldAndItalicsFont);
```

**Output:**

```
Normal Font: Avenir-Book Size: 14
Italics Font: Avenir-BookOblique
Bold Font: Avenir-Black
Bold and Italics Font: Avenir-BlackOblique
```

The advantage here is that I no longer need to create the individual font types myself, and a font from the family is sufficient to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Checkout `NSAttributedString.Key.obliqueness`. Setting the value of this key to values other than 0 make the text italics with different degree.

Comment: This works for characters such as Chinese or Korean which do not support Italic! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.3.1

### Solution

```
extension UIFont {
    class func systemFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat, symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont? {
        return UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize).including(symbolicTraits: symbolicTraits)
    }

    func including(symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont? {
        var _symbolicTraits = self.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        _symbolicTraits.update(with: symbolicTraits)
        return withOnly(symbolicTraits: _symbolicTraits)
    }

    func excluding(symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont? {
        var _symbolicTraits = self.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
        _symbolicTraits.remove(symbolicTraits)
        return withOnly(symbolicTraits: _symbolicTraits)
    }

    func withOnly(symbolicTraits: UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits) -> UIFont? {
        guard let fontDescriptor = fontDescriptor.withSymbolicTraits(symbolicTraits) else { return nil }
        return .init(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15).including(symbolicTraits: .traitBold)
font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, symbolicTraits: [.traitBold, .traitItalic])
font = font.excluding(symbolicTraits: [.traitBold]
font = font.withOnly(symbolicTraits: [])
```

### Full sample

> Do not forget to **paste the solution code here**.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addLabel(origin: .init(x: 20, y: 20), font: .systemFont(ofSize: 15, symbolicTraits: [.traitBold, .traitItalic]))
        addLabel(origin: .init(x: 20, y: 40), font: UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15).including(symbolicTraits: .traitBold))
        guard let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, symbolicTraits: [.traitBold, .traitItalic]) else { return }
        addLabel(origin: .init(x: 20, y: 60), font: font.excluding(symbolicTraits: [.traitBold]))
        addLabel(origin: .init(x: 20, y: 80), font: font.withOnly(symbolicTraits: []))
    }

    private func addLabel(origin: CGPoint, font: UIFont?) {
        guard let font = font else { return }
        let label = UILabel(frame: .init(origin: origin, size: .init(width: 200, height: 40)))
        label.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello World!", attributes: [.font: font, .foregroundColor: UIColor.black ])
        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Very helpful solution. After seeing this, my plan for the text apps I will build is to provide users with only fonts that have both bold and italic traits.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to the question, per-se, but SwiftUI, as of iOS 15, supports Markdown natively in Text views.  This may suffice if your need is only emboldening or italicising a portion of a string (and you're using SwiftUI, of course!)  e.g.

```swift
VStack {
    Text("This is regular text.")
    Text("* This is **bold** text, this is *italic* text, and this is ***bold, italic*** text.")
    Text("~~A strikethrough example~~")
    Text("`Monospaced works too`")
    Text("Visit Apple: [click here](https://apple.com)")
}
```

(The example is lifted straight from [hackingwithswift.com](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-markdown-content-in-text))